# Nativescript/Google Geocoding JSON Parse

Tags: json, api, nativescript, reverse-geocoding

I am reading a geocoding from Google API in my Nativescript code. The results are coming this way:

```
{"_bodyInit":"{\n   \"results\" : [\n      {\n         \"address_components\" : [\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"Cooper City\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"Cooper City\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"locality\", \"political\" ]\n            },\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"Broward County\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"Broward County\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"administrative_area_level_2\", \"political\" ]\n            },\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"Florida\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"FL\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"administrative_area_level_1\", \"political\" ]\n            },\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"United States\",\n               \"short_name\" : \"US\",\n               \"types\" : [ \"country\", \"political\" ]\n            }\n         ],\n         \"formatted_address\" : \"Cooper City, FL, USA\",\n         \"geometry\" : {\n
```

[image]

when reading from this code:

```
fetchModule.fetch(geoPlace, {
    method: "GET"
})
.then(function(response) {
    alert({title: "GET Response", message: JSON.stringify(response), okButtonText: "Close"});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
}, function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
})
```

My question is, how to get access, for example, to "Cooper City"?

I have tried (without success):

```
console.log(response.value["results"])
console.log(response[0])
console.log(response.results[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

making a revision of the response I identify that it is not a successful JSON format, you should look for the way to convert it into JSON format to be able to use its code and get to the tag you need.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: That's likely due to the fact that he JSON.stringifies a JSON already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I found the solution:

```
var m = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit)
console.log(m.results[0].address_components[1].short_name)
```

For some reason I don't know the original results did not return as a valid JSON.